# Anchor tag href attribute incorrect in IE11 during ace editor change event

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, ace-editor

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R3VbC/4/

In the example fiddle, I run the parseHref function when the ace editor's value changes. This in turn passes a string to an anchor element which is used to normalise the url. You can also click the Parse href button to run this function directly.

```
var parseHref = function() 
    var anchorNodeHrefOriginal = urlParsingNode.href;
    urlParsingNode.setAttribute("href", 'my-href')
    var firstPassHref = urlParsingNode.href;
    urlParsingNode.setAttribute("href", firstPassHref)
    var finalHref = urlParsingNode.href;
    $('#original-href').html(anchorNodeHrefOriginal);
    $('#first-pass-href').html(firstPassHref);
    $('#final-href').html(finalHref);
}

editor.getSession().on('change', parseHref)
```

This replicates the functionality used by angularJS to resolve url (see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/urlUtils.js)). This is relevant as I am trying to embed the ace editor in an angular app.

To reproduce the issue I am experiencing, copy and paste some text (do not just type it!) into the editor. In chrome, the values of the text displayed at the bottom should all be something like http://fiddle.jshell.net/R3VbC/4/show/my-href. If you do the same thing in IE11, the values displayed are simply 'my-href'.

If run this parseHref function in any other way, such as typing into the editor or clicking the parse href button, you get the desired result (i.e. http://fiddle.jshell.net/R3VbC/4/show/my-href). It only seems to give the incorrect value if you copy and paste text into the editor.

This could also be worked around by executing the parseHref function from window.setTimeout (see http://jsfiddle.net/R3VbC/5/)

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function() {
    window.setTimeout(parseHref);
})
```

So it appears that somehow the ace editor is preventing anchor tags from resolving correctly in IE11 during the change event. Why is this happening and can it be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ie11 error which happens with textarea too http://jsfiddle.net/R3VbC/6/.
urlParsingNode.setAttribute("href", firstPassHref) doesn't work when called from paste event.

try

```
textarea.addEventListener("paste", function(){
     parseHref()
})
// not very a useful code snippet, but without it 
// this `extremely intelligent` site removes jsfiddle link:(
```

But more importantly you shouldn't do any slow operations, like accessing dom, from change event, use editor 'input' event which is fired with ~30ms timeout, or use your own longer timeout.